# The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error and 1 warning

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, ipod, podspec

I am trying to publish my library with cocoas pod but I get this error saying [!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error and 1 warning.

Below is the podspec file content which I am using to for the initial information.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "EasyGrids"
  s.version      = "1.0.0"
  s.summary      = "EasyGrids is a control to create photo collections and grids easy"
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/shoaibahmedqureshi/EasyGrids"
  s.license      = "MIT"
  s.author       = {"Shoaib Ahmed Qureshi" => "shoaib.elastica@gmail.com" }
  s.source       = {:git => "https://github.com/shoaibahmedqureshi/EasyGrids.git",:tag => "1.0.0"}
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.source_files  = "EasyGrids/*"
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the complete output of command to verify pod file

```
pod spec lint --verbose

    EasyGrids (1.0.0) - Analyzing on macOS platform.
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-App`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `EasyGrids` from `/Users/shoaibahmedqureshi/Desktop/EasyGrids/EasyGrids.podspec`

Resolving dependencies of 

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  A EasyGrids

Downloading dependencies

-> Installing EasyGrids (1.0.0)
 > Git download
 > Git download
     $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/shoaibahmedqureshi/EasyGrids.git
     /var/folders/dk/5yk3ccs53z30tdtnr29hn9l80000gn/T/d20180502-27371-1jbttzs
     --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 1.0.0
     Cloning into '/var/folders/dk/5yk3ccs53z30tdtnr29hn9l80000gn/T/d20180502-27371-1jbttzs'...
 -> EasyGrids (1.0.0)
    - WARN  | url: There was a problem validating the URL https://github.com/shoaibahmedqureshi/EasyGrids.
    - ERROR | [OSX] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Pod::DSLError
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:683:in `rescue in _eval_podspec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:676:in `_eval_podspec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:584:in `block in from_string'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:581:in `chdir'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:581:in `from_string'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:564:in `from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/podspec_finder.rb:15:in `block in podspecs'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/podspec_finder.rb:14:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/podspec_finder.rb:14:in `podspecs'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:82:in `download_request'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:171:in `download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:154:in `block in uncached_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:181:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:181:in `in_tmpdir'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:153:in `uncached_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:33:in `download_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:42:in `download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:120:in `download_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:60:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:364:in `install_source_of_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:329:in `block (2 levels) in install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:85:in `titled_section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:328:in `block in install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:320:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:320:in `install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:163:in `block in download_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `download_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:427:in `block in download_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:427:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:427:in `download_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:309:in `block in perform_extensive_analysis'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:303:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:303:in `perform_extensive_analysis'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:83:in `validate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:70:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:57:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:57:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
) during validation.

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error and 1 warning.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:87:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `MBProgressHud.h` is not found when compiling `UtilitiesHelper.h`. Are you missing a dependency in your Podspec?

Comment: MBProgressHud.h is part of my project as you can see my git hub repo.

Comment: I don't know, but that is the error message I got when I ran a `pod lib lint --verbose`

Comment: I see that error as well but I am wondering what could be wrong as it compiles and fine and the files showing missing are all part of project.

Comment: pod lib lint --verbose seems to work fine as it only gives warning which i can take care of later on however pod spec lint --verbose still throws same error . Any idea ?

Comment: Is any solution found for the above error?